# unconfigured table schema_columnfamilies

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli, bigdata

I am new to cassandra and I am using cassandra version 2.1.17 which supports cassandra-cli . I created a keyspace using the following command

```
create keyspace employee with placement_strategy='org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy' and strategy_options = {replication_factor:1};
```

However when I use the command
`use employee;`

I get the following error

```
unconfigured table schema_columnfamilies
```

I am unable to understand what is the issue. Can someone help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which cassandra's cqlsh are you using ?

Comment: Why don't you use cqlsh ?

Comment: Unfortunately , I am not allowed to use cqlsh.

Comment: The table `schema_columnfamilies` should present cassandra version lower than `Cassandra 3.0`

Comment: how do i achieve this?

Comment: Not allowed?  Whomever is forcing you to use the cassandra-cli over cqlsh should be fired.  Just sayin'.

Comment: @Aaron : Completely agree with you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution. The issue was that I had previously installed another version of cassandra and uninstalled it. It turned out that even though i uninstalled the application , some processes of previous version were still running. I killed those processes manually and restarted the cassandra server.

Comment: Can I get details? I have the same issue :-)

Comment: This error comes when you have installed multiple versions of cassandra. I used ps -ef command in terminal and saw that some of the processes for other version of cassandra was running eventhough i had uninstalled it